# how to use ggradar without rescale changing the results

Tags: r, ggplot2

reading the `ggradar` documentation and error discussion pages, to use ggradar, data must be first be rescaled, which changes my data structure. I am not restricted to using ggradar only, although I am having difficulty downloading `ggiraph::ggRadar`

The result currently is a percentage, scaled:

[image]

Whereas I would like it to be scaled based on the mean of a grouped variable (Domain) to look something like this:

[image]

Data to create the first `ggradar` graphic:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggradar)

df <- tribble(~Question_Code,   ~RespondentLevel,
"Engagement - Inclusion",   5,
"External engagement - policies",   2,
"External engagement - technology", 5,
"Community data",   5,
"Internal engagement",  5,
"Internal use of technology",   4,
"Familiarity/Alignment",    5,
"Environmental impacts",    5,
"Innovation",   2,
"Use of open-source technology",    2,
"Regulation of hardware & software",    5,
"In-house technical capacity",  5,
"Infrastructure procurement",   5,
"Algorithmic Error & Bias", 2,
"Control: Privacy", 5,
"Accountability in Governance Structures",  3,
"Open procurement", 5,
"Use in decision-making",   1,
"Accountability",   1,
"External Control", 4,
"Internal Control", 2,
"Open Data",    2)

#add the grouping variable:
df <- df %>% mutate(Domain = c(as.character((rep("Domain 1", 5))),
                  as.character(rep("Domain 2", 4)),
                  as.character(rep("Domain 3", 6)),
                  as.character(rep("Domain 4", 7))))
```

And for the graphic itself:

```
df %>% mutate(ID = 1) %>% spread(Domain, RespondentLevel, fill = 0)%>%
  mutate_at(vars(`Domain 1`:`Domain 4`), rescale) %>% 
  select(ID, `Domain 1`:`Domain 4`) %>% 
  ggradar(legend.position = "none")
```

When summarized as a mean, the rescaled values are too small to be used, although what I need is a mean of the RespondentLevel variable, grouped by Domain.